# How badly does 'Hunker Down' limit my units sight?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I understand that the Hunker Down command gives a defensive bonus and a sight penalty. Does anyone know exactly what this penalty is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you see that yellow circle around them when they are in the hunker down state? That's now their sight radius.

Answer (score 0):

The circle is the sight radius, however their sight radius is only relevent to snipers with the perk that they can shoot at enemys in squadmates line of sight as by hunkering down you've ended the soldiers turn for a defensive boost.

Comment: The sight range is also useful to observe enemy movement. Sure, when the move of the alien ends in the normal sight range, the soldier will spot it as soon as the player turn starts. But you lose the information where they came from and when the alien just passes through the sight area, you won't spot it.